# What is the proper syntax for downloading a torrent from many different sources?

Tags: command-line-arguments, bittorrent, download-manager

I am looking to download a single torrent file containing several items of interest. Note: I am ultimately after the items of interest, not the torrent file itself.

I understand that aria is capable of downloading the same set of files from multiple sources, and I would like to do so because the files are huge.

I have access to: the torrent file download link, the torrent magnet link, and a local copy of the torrent file. Q1: is this the limit on how 'fast' I can download the torrent files?

Q2: What is the proper syntax for utilizing all sources to download the set of files? So far I have:

$ aria2c --torrent-file=$HOME/Downloads/torrent_name.torrent 'magnet_link' --follow-torrent=True 'url_to_torrent.torrent'

As always I think I'm mucking something up. Thoughts very welcome. Cheers.

Comment: A .torrent file, a full magnet link, and a torrent link will all resolve to the same sources (the tracker's peers and whatever you can find in your client's DHT). Specifying multiple of them is redundant. You may want to tune your client's peer limits, if the defaults are lower than your connection can support, but that's all I have to suggest. The multi-source download feature seems more intended for additional full HTTP/FTP sources of the file. (Thanks for pointing this out, though, it looks like it might be the sort of torrent client I had been looking for a while ago.)

Comment: Ah yes that makes some sense, thanks for your response. I just pulled this from the man page:

You can specify both torrent file with -T option and URIs. By doing this,
 download a file from both torrent swarm and HTTP/FTP server at the same time,
 while the data from HTTP/FTP are uploaded to the torrent swarm. For single file
 torrents, URI can be a complete URI pointing to the resource or if URI ends
 with '/', 'name' in torrent file is added. For multi-file torrents, 'name' and
 'path' in torrent are added to form a URI for each file.

Does this mean local + other URI?

Comment: I think that's referring to torrent data in any form, plus an HTTP/FTP/SFTP URL. This is equivalent to the HTTP seeding that's natively supported by most torrent clients (and used by Stack Exchange's own data torrents), but manually configured. I don't think there's anything you can do unless you have another HTTP/FTP/SFTP source yourself. But I've never used this specific software before, so I may be misunderstanding.